# Insert an HTML Tag Into an Angular Directive

Tags: html, angularjs, dom, tags, directive

I want to use an Angular directive to wrap a Bootstrap panel. I'm running into a problem, though, if I want to use HTML tags within the body of the panel.

Given:

```
$scope.panel = {
  title: "Title",
  body: "This is some <strong>cool</strong> text!"
};
```

I would want my panel to render with a body that looks like:

This is some **cool** text!

But instead it's rendering as:

```
This is some <strong>cool</strong> text!
```

Is it possible to achieve the effect I'm looking for?

Edit:

Directive

```
aModule.directive('myPanel', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: { panel: '=' },
    templateUrl: './tmp/my-panel.html'
  };
});
```

Template:

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">{{panel.title}}</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <p>{{panel.body}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

In use:

```
<my-panel panel="panel"></my-panel>
```

Using the answer below:

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">{{panel.title}}</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <p ng-bind-html="panel.body"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To bind HTML to an Angular variable, you have to use the [`$sce`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce) module's [`trustAsHtml`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce#trustAsHtml) function to verify the content.

```
$scope.panel = {
  title: "Title",
  body: $sce.trustAsHtml("This is some <strong>cool</strong> text!");
};
```

You also need to use [`ng-bind-html`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml):

```
<p ng-bind-html="panel['body']"></p>
```

You no longer need the `{{ panel.body }}` since the `ng-bind-html` directive will evaluate the expression and insert the resulting HTML into the desired element in a secure way.

Comment: Binding to the variable isn't the issue by itself, you have to use `ng-bind-html` which is why you use `$sce`

Comment: @charlietfl you are right! Let me update my answer accordingly.

Comment: and to make my point clearer...the variable can have html in it with no issues...it's only how you use it that matters